# ng-repeat for an json object which has arrays

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a JSON object which is data for a chart. This has 2 properties labels and data. Both are arrays. Along with the chart I wish to display a table as well. I am not able to figure out how to use the ng-repeat directive here.

**JSON Object**

```
$scope.chartdata={
          labels: ["XYZ", "ABC","DEF"],
          data: [4286, 38870, 3955]
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Labels</th>
            <th>Data </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="cht in chartdata">
            <td>{{cht.labels}}</td>
            <td>{{cht.data}}</td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
```

Do I need to change the JSON structure? I do not wish to cos it works for my chart directive and I want to resues the same JSON for displaying the table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $index, because these are 2 separate properties within the chartdata object

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Labels</th>
            <th>Data </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="label in chartdata.labels">
        <td>{{label}}</td>
        <td>{{chartdata.data[$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

That said the object structure you have can probably be revised to be more like the model (**unless you are using the object structure for something else** that expects it in that format)

```
$scope.chartdata = [
      {
          label: "XYZ",
          data: 4286
      },
      ...
];
```

In the latter case too, you could use the above structure and set up a method that transforms the object into the dual array structure that you need for *the something else*.